# C# Ta-Lib Exponential Moving average(EMA) calculation

Tags: c#, financial, ta-lib

I am using the Ta-lib library in my C# project to calculate Exponential moving averages. I have to calculate EMA for 20 periods. I did my calculation on a spreadsheet (Excel) and I got the correct result; while using the same data points with ta-lib library I am getting wrong result.

I am using close price from the attached image.

```
Core.Ema(startIdx, endIdx, close, 20, out outBegIdx, out outNBElement, smoothClose);
```

after running ta-lib function my result is

```
113.783380952381
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
```

While running the EMA formula on Excel with same period values my result is mentioned in attached image

[image]

Comment: Technically, a 20-period EMA is zero until the 21st period. You need to deal with how the formula handles answers under the minimum period threshold. As to why the 2st period is different, are you using different weighting methods? EMA calcs allow for all kinds of different weighting methods and some use HL/2 some use OHLC/4 some use C only

Comment: NO I am using the regular approach for Weighting method. like 2/n+1

Comment: I am using only C for now

Comment: you mean If i am trying to calculate EMA(20) I need 21 data points ?

Comment: Yes - when you think og if, EMA-20 is an "exponential moving average" of 20 datapoints. If we're using days, then 20 trading days (usually four weeks). It isn't possible to have a 20-day moving average of fewer than 20 days' trading. So you can't have a simple moving average of fewer data points than are in the sample period - weighting them helps even less. Moving averages (both simple and exponential) don't usually start on graphs until the 1st trading day after the number of periods surveyed. Sometime people might fill them in with 1 day/2 day/2 day/4 day etc. but those aren't real 21 day

Answer (score 1):

One other note is that your data order is reversed. The dates should be ascending in your array with the latest date being the last entry and the earliest date being the first entry